# How can I translate a Django website entirely?

Tags: django, translation, django-translated-fields

I have a Django project. How can I translate the entire website? It's worth noting that additional data can be added to the database later, so I want to translate all the existing data in the database, including information added later.

---

Answer (score -2):

You can enable Internationalization in the settings file of your Django app. And do the data in your models, you can use django modeltranslation library to do that. I hope this gives you the answer.

Comment: but this way needed to manually translate

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? This is correct though. Though there should be some default words(admin) that are auto translated. other words that is in your webpage or database needs to be manually setup.

Comment: Or you can use google chrome's page translation. This will be on your user's action

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).